# How match non string in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to match non string in `xslt 2.0`.

```
<td><list>
        <list-item>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <list>
                <list-item>
                    <p>bbb</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
    </list>
</td>
```

I have done a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="td">
    <para>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tps:p>
</xsl:template>
```

When input xml like below:

```
<td><list>
        <list-item>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <list>
                <list-item>
                    <p>bbb</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
    </list>
kmkmkmk
</td>
```

Output(**correct output**):

```
<para>kmkmkmk</para>
```

When input xml like below (new line between td and list):

```
<td><list>
        <list-item>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <list>
                <list-item>
                    <p>bbb</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
    </list>
</td>
```

Output(**Incorrect output**):

```
<para> </para>
```

But When input xml like below( no new line between td and list ):

```
<td><list>
        <list-item>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <list>
                <list-item>
                    <p>bbb</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
    </list></td>
```

Output(**correct output**):

```
nothing display
```

I want to do when `td` has no any text nothing display and display only display `td` has text.

Why when there is a new line between `<td>` and `<list>` not working well and where is no new line working wells. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your samples are not minimal and complete but to transform a `td` element node which has non-whitespace text child contents you can use

```
<xsl:template match="td[text()[normalize-space()]]">
  <para>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </para>
</xsl:template>
```

Whether you additionally need `<xsl:template match="td[not(text()[normalize-space()])]"/>` or `<xsl:template match="td[not(text()[normalize-space()])]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` depends on how you set up the rest of the transformation.